# json 間の構造的な diff を取るには？

Tags: json, unix

json 間の構造的な diff が取りたいです。これを実現する方法はありますか。

イメージとしては、 `jsondiff a.json b.json` とやると、 json の構造的な差分が出力されるようなツールです。(`a.json`, `b.json` はそれぞれ、単一の json オブジェクトからなるテキストファイル)

背景としては、２つの、 type 定義にそこそこの差異が発生している ES サーバー２つがあったときに (しかし、おそらく半分ぐらいの構造は一致している、、はず) 、その mapping の定義 (SQL でいう create 文の集合のようなもの) の差分を取得したい、がやりたいことです。
REST api をたたいて、それぞれから mapping 定義を json を取得した状態で、ここから差分を計算しようとしているのですが、いいツールがあるといいなと思いながら質問しています。

---

参考のために、 Elasticsearch から取得できる mapping 情報 json がどのようなものかというと、 [公式サイト](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) より例えば次のような形です。

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "user": {
      "_all":       { "enabled": false  },
      "properties": {
        "title":    { "type": "string"  },
        "name":     { "type": "string"  },
        "age":      { "type": "integer" }
      }
    },
    "blogpost": {
      "properties": {
        "title":    { "type": "string"  },
        "body":     { "type": "string"  },
        "user_id":  {
          "type":   "string",
          "index":  "not_analyzed"
        },
        "created":  {
          "type":   "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

使えそうなツールがありました。どうでしょうか。

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-diff
- https://github.com/stefankoegl/python-json-patch

Comment: json-diff が、自分のほしいような動きをしていると確認しました。

Answer (score 1):

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)コマンドでJSONを整形して、その差分をとるのはどうでしょうか。`--sort-keys` / `-S` フラグは任意ですが、オブジェクトのキーは揃えたほうが無難でしょう。

JSONを整形出力するコマンドは `python -m json.tool` でも代用できると思います。

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

json_pretty='jq . --sort-keys'

diff -u <($json_pretty $1) <($json_pretty $2)
```

実行例

```
$ jsondiff.sh a.json b.json
--- /dev/fd/63  2016-04-20 02:57:59.000000000 +0900
+++ /dev/fd/62  2016-04-20 02:57:59.000000000 +0900
@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@
   "mappings": {
     "user": {
       "_all": {
-        "enabled": false
+        "enabled": true
       },
       "properties": {
         "title": {
```

Comment: `-S` オプションに +1。しかし、これで試してみたのですが、 diff の計算上違う type (例でいうところの `user` や `blogpost`) が違う場所に diff として発生したりなどしているので、やはり厳密な構造的な diff が取れるならとりたい、と思っている次第です。。（質問文を更新しました： 微妙に違っているのではなくって、割と違っていることが判明しました。。すいません。)